# ¿Cuál es la etimología de «soroche»?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, etimología

Hay varias palabras que significan "[Mountain Sickness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_sickness)" (en inglés).  Los que parecen evidente incluyen «mal de altura», «mal de montaña», «mal de páramo», etc.

Pero, la palabra «soroche» (según la [página Wikide *Mal de montaña*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mal_de_monta%C3%B1a) en español) es nueva para mí.  ¿Cuál es su etimología?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El DRAE lo recoge:

> [**soroche**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YQG25S0)
>   Voz quechua.
>   1. m. Arg., Bol., Chile, Col., Ec., Perú y Ur. mal de montaña.
>   2. m. Chile. [galena](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IjPKfZf).

Como ves, indica que es una palabra de origen [quechua](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguas_quechuas) que se usa en Argentina, Bolivia, Chile, Colombia, Ecuador, Perú y Uruguay (trascendió los Andes, según parece).

Buscando un poco más encuentro en blog de redacción → [La palabra del día: Soroche](http://blog.pucp.edu.pe/blog/blogderedaccion/2009/04/22/la-palabra-del-d-a-soroche/):

> Soroche, como confirma un estudio de Rodolfo Cerrón-Palomino, **proviene del vocablo quechua “suruchiq” que significa, según el Inca Garcilaso de la vega, “el metal que hace deslizar la plata”**. Esto sucede porque esta palabra designaba el nombre de un metal que servía, durante el tiempo del virreinato, para fundir la plata. Asimismo, es en este contexto minero en el que soroche adquiere el nuevo significado de “metal bajo”. Luego, **designará “mal de altura” porque se relacionarán al trabajo y los efectos de este metal en las minas con el malestar que producía a aquellas personas que transportaban el mineral en la sociedad colonial**. Por tanto, ya para el siglo XVII, el significado de soroche sería el actual, como se registra entre algunos escritores de ese tiempo. Por ejemplo, el Inca Garcilaso define soroche como los efectos del cambio repentino de la temperatura de los llanos a la frigidez de las punas, y viceversa.

Hablan de él también en ['Dolores le tiene miedo a Dolorán' y otras enfermedades típicas de Bogotá](https://www.civico.com/bogota/noticias/enfermedades-y-dolencias-tipicas-de-bogota).

---

Arriba vimos que la segunda acepción de *soroche* es *galena*:

> **galena**
>   Del lat. galēna, voz de or. hisp.
>   1. f. Mineral compuesto de azufre y plomo, de color gris y lustre intenso. Es la mejor mena del plomo.

Por lo que da la sensacion de que *galena* sigue de alguna forma ligado con este metal descrito por la referencia.

Comment: Interesante. En España no la había escuchado nunca.

Comment: @SergioTx será que en España no tenemos montañas lo suficientemente altas :)

Comment: También es cierto. Pero "mal de altura" sí que lo he escuchado.